# PHP if variable = 1 new variable = something else

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I want to do a test in PHP to see if `form_id = "1"` then `form_name = "Test form 1"` and then if the `form_id = "2"` the `form_name` would be `"General Enquiries"` for example.

How can this be one in PHP.

I can see how to echo a result but not turn it into a new variable.

Thanks
Roy

Comment: What you're looking for is called variable assignment. It works pretty close how you describe the problem in your question even. See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Answer (score 4):

A simple if statement could do it:

```
if($form_id==1)
   $form_name='form 1 result';
elseif($form_id==2)
   $form_name='general inquiries';
```

But this makes for many nested statements when you get more possible form id's, a switch statement solves this problem

```
 switch($form_id) {
    case 1:
       $form_name='form 1 name';
       break;
    case 2:
       $form_name='general enquiry';
       break;
    case 3:
       $form_name='an added form';
       break;
    default:
       $form_name='unknown form'
 }
```

To learn more about the switch statement, go [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

There is also a short notation for conditional values, see it as an if statement with a variable assignment in short form.

```
$form_name = ($form_id == 1) ? 'form 1 result' : 'enquiry';
```

In this case, PHP first evaluates the expression before the question mark. If it is true, the value right behind the question mark is returned, otherwise, the value after the colon is returned. You can also nest these:

```
$form_name = ($form_id==1) ? ''form 1 result' : ($form_id==2) ? 'enquiry form' : 'unknown form';
```

EDIT from a slightly older, slightly more experienced me: I usually avoid nesting these expressions. It's often harder to understand than just using if-statements, or putting the "inner" ternary expression into its own variable.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
if ($form_id == 1)
{
    $form_name = "Test form 1";
}
elseif ($form_id == 2)
{
    $form_name = "General Enquiries";
}
else
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($form_id == 1){ $formname = "Test form 1";} 
if ($form_id == 2){ $formname = "General Enquiries";}

echo $formname;
```